# Regex to Filter out ">" and "=20" from email.message_from_string

Tags: python, regex, encoding, mime

I want to write a regular expression to filter out all junk out of an email that is being pulled in through imaplib and email modules in my Python script below. I'm thinking a regex is best but feel free to suggest better solutions.  Any idea why the email text has a equals in the word *be=tter* below?  The original email has it as *better*.

**Python snippet:**

```
emailMessage = email.message_from_string
print emailMessage.get_payload():
```

**Print Text:**

```
>=20
> >>>>
> >>>> Hope this makes it through you spam filter but couldn't think of a be=
tter subject.
> >>>>
```

Comment: You don't really want to "filter out" `=20`. It is part of the encoding, called "quoted-printable". You want to decode it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Karl Knechtel says in the comments, your message is encoded as [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable). To decode that, use [`quopri.decodestring()`](http://docs.python.org/library/quopri.html#quopri.decodestring):

```
import quopri

decoded = quopri.decodestring(emailMessage.get_payload())
```

Using regexes to strip out the "junk" characters is going to be inefficient, and also means that whenever a new one turns up in your input down the line, you'll have to modify your code.

However, if after decoding you want to lose the `>` characters [and any whitespace betwwen them] at the beginning of each line, then for *that*, a regex is a reasonable solution:

```
import re

chevrons = re.compile("(?m)^[> ]*")
stripped = re.sub(chevrons, "", decoded)
```

`(?m)` indicates that the regex is [multiline](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE), by the way.

Comment: thanks for the response, any difference between quopri.decodestring and part.get_payload(decode=True)?

Comment: By the looks of it, no ... I hadn't been aware that option existed. Learn something every day etc. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If your message matches below regex then filter out:

```
         ^>=\d$
```

i.e.

```
  if not (re.match('^>=\d$', emailMessage)):
    print emailMessage.get_payload():
```